# Decode in SQL vs. If... Else in Java

Tags: java, sql, db2

I'm looking for a solution to a simple scenario. I need to check if a value is present in a table, and if present I need `Y` else `N`

I can do it in two ways, either fetch the count of rows from the database, and code the logic in java, or use `DECODE(COUNT(*),0,'N','Y')`

Which is better? Is there any advantage of one over the other? Or more specifically, is there any disadvantage of using `DECODE()` instead of doing it in Java?

The database I have is DB2.

Comment: It's impossible to say which is better for you. Do what you're most comfortable in that will be easiest to use and maintain. If that doesn't work, do it the other way.

Comment: It really depends of how big of a resource hit the DECODE is. A single if else in JAVA will happen so quick it wont even be noticeable.

Comment: The `decode()` call is exactly as I've shown

Comment: Also, you do not need to count them all to determine that there are none.

Comment: @Forklift Didn't get what you mean by not needing to count them all to determine there are none?

Comment: @inquisitive I see that, but I am not sure what exactly the impact is on the database side. Do the select with the code and without the decode if the return is significantly slower, use the IF ELSE. If they are close, just use the DECODE. It is always better to receive the information as required if there is no down side

Comment: If there are a million rows, your query has to count them all just to reply 'Y'. Might be better to combine EXISTS with IF .. ELSE

Comment: @Forklift makes a good point

Comment: Indeed, you might instead use `case when exists(select 1 from my_table where my_column = my_value) then 'Y' else 'N' end`.  The DBMS does not then need to count all the rows matching the criterion.

Comment: if I say `select count(*) from table_name where column_name=value` it does not have to count a million rows, does it? It just has to count the number of rows remaining after the where clause! Am I right?

Comment: You need to be careful when using count as it could be performance hit, you need to verify looking at explain plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `exists`.  I would tend to do this as:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from . . . .)
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as flag
from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

The reason you want to use `exists` is because it is faster.  When you use `count(*)`, the SQL engine has to process *all* the (appropriate) data to get the count.  With `exists`, it can stop at the first one.

The reason to prefer `case` over `decode()` is that the former is ANSI standard SQL, available in basically all databases.

Comment: Unlike many of the comments which claim there is no way to know which is faster, it is clear that using EXISTS in this way will be faster than count(*) and client logic.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be any considerable difference between those 2 ways that you mentioned. 
1) The DECODE will be simple and the IF will be simple. 
2) You will be receiving an Int32 versus a CHAR(1) - which is not a significant difference.

So, I would consider another aspect: Which of those 2 will make your code more CLEAR?

And one more thing: if this is the ONLY thing that you're selecting on that query, you could try something like:

```
SELECT 'Y' FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YOURTABLE WHERE YOURCONDITION = 1); --Oracle SQL - but should be fairly easy to translate it to DB2
```

This is an option to not make the DB count for every occurrence of your condition just to check if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregated functions like count can be optimized with MQT - Materilized Query Tables

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0509melnyk/

```
connect to sample

alter table employee add unique (empno)
alter table department add unique (deptno)

create table count_emp_dpto_1 as (select d.deptno, e.empno, count(*) from employee e, department d where  d.deptno = 1 and  e.workdept = d.deptno) data initially deferred refresh immediate

set integrity for count_emp_dpto_1 immediate checked not incremental

select * from count_emp_dpto_1

connect reset
```